# iOS - UISearchBar textfield background black on focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have an issue with a UISearchBar. In the Storyboard its bar tint is set to clearColor, its Search Style to Minimal and Bar Style to Default. I have a custom background image too.

This is how it looks like by default, when the view is first loaded:
[image]

That's exactly how I want it to be.

Now, when I press on it to type some text, here is what happens:

[image]

The background becomes black. If I cancel or stop the search, it goes back to image number one, perfectly.
I have tried plenty of things, setting everything in code, but I can't seem to change this black background. I simply want it to be clear color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like black background due to Clear bar tint Color.There is no need to set bar tint color as **Clear Color**.set it as **Default**.

Comment: It doesn't change anything sadly.

Comment: Ohhh..I have set same property and it is working for me.

Comment: @bloemy Did you enable traslucent property ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually The UISearchBar offer method to set the background of textfield in Searchbar. It is:

- (void)setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:(nullable UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

You can use it to set any image you can.

Answer (score 0):

try this code on viewDidLoad

```
self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.searchController.searchBar.translucent = YES;
```

and I found that in UISearchController it have those property may affect the presentation of UISearchBar.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation __TVOS_PROHIBITED; // default is YES, and has the same behavior as obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation.
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_1); // default is YES
```

try to set them to `NO` also

```
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```